# Should I insert is/was/were after an 'if'?

Tags: tenses, conditionals

I have the following sentence:

> if the foo is/was/were a bar and the baz truck a qux, how does the
>   working of a baz relate to coaching?

Should it be is/was/were? Searching the internet just give me a lot of conflicting answers, so I'm here to hear (hmm that rhymes!) from the experts!

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: @BarrieEngland  Irrelevant - they're just syntactic placeholders.

Comment: @StoneyB. Oh, thanks. The 'coaching' bit made me think it might have been something to do with American football!

Comment: @BarrieEngland [*foo*, *bar*, *baz* and *qux*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) are the classic stand-ins for variable names in texts on programming; *foo* and *bar* have a disreputable past in [US military slang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_slang_terms#FUBAR).

Comment: @StoneyB. New to me, I'm afraid. I am, however, familiar with SNAFU.

Comment: This would have been a better puzzle with meaningful words.  Suggest also showing the alternatives as three separate, complete sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to rephrase your sample sentence a little: expand your ellipsis in the conditional clause and translate the main clause from the interrogative to the indicative. In the main clause your *does* means that we must be speaking of a **current** relationship:

- If FOO ***is*** a BAR, and BAZ ***is*** QUX, then the relationship between BAZ and coaching ***is*** X.

  *This is an acceptable conditional: it describes what you consider to be a general truth.*
- If FOO ***was*** a BAR, and BAZ ***was*** QUX, then the relationship between BAZ and coaching ***is*** X.

  *This is marginally acceptable: it describes what you consider to be a generally true inference from historical contingencies. It would be a bit clearer if you changed the verb in the main clause:*

  . . .  then the relationship between BAZ and coaching ***must be*** X.
- <sup>✲</sup>If FOO ***were*** a BAR, and BAZ ***were*** QUX, then the relationship between BAZ and coaching ***is*** X.

  *This is not acceptable: it presents the conditional as an* ***irrealis***, *as something which is not known to be true, and it requires a corresponding uncertainty in the verb of the main clause:*

  ... then the relationship between BAZ and coaching ***would be*** X.

Answer (score 1):

These three options are all valid in a sense that they are grammatical. In short, *is* would indicate that the condition is in present tense, *was* would indicate that the condition is in past tense and *were* would indicate [a counterfactual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_past_subjunctive).

Answer (score -1):

**Were**.

"If the foo *were* a bar..."

Being part of an if-clause puts the verb in the [subjunctive case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive).  The verb "to be" is the only verb in English that has a different spelling in that case.

Comment: Not so. *If* calls for *were* only where the protasis is uncertain or known to be false. "If A is 1 and B is 2, then A plus B equals 3."

Comment: Thanks, @StoneyB for the excellent terse summary of that rule.